# Please help with a subquery that includes Order By and a second child relationship

Tags: query, conga, subquery

I've learned a lot about Salesforce querying but also have a lot to learn. I hope this question is clear.

I have a lookup relationship where Restrictions__c is the parent and Actions__c is the child (API name Actions_Restrictions__c), another where Actions__c is the parent and Restrictions__c is the child (API name Action_Id__c), and another where HR__c is the parent and Actions__c is the child (API name HR__c).

I need to return field Restriction_Description__c on Restrictions__c where the CreatedDate (or could use the ID auto number field) field on Actions__c is the most recent one, and where the HR ID field is '[###].

Using Salesforce Developer Console for starters, this query returns data but doesn't limit the data to just the most recent HR.ID:

```
SELECT Name, Restriction_Description__c, 
     (SELECT CreatedDate FROM Actions__r 
        WHERE HR__r.Name = '[###]' 
        ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1) 
      FROM Restrictions__c 
      WHERE Action_ID__r.HR__c = '[###]'
```

Can you please suggest what changes are needed to return Restriction_Description__c for only the most recent CreatedDate?

Also, strange to me that instead of returning a column called CreatedDate on Actions__r, it returns a column called Actions__r that has no data. Why is that?

The query is going to be used in a Conga query.

Thank you.

Comment: This queries a `Restriction` whose parent Action has `HR__c = '[###]'` but is fetching the Restriction's children Actions that also have `HR__c = '[###]'`. Those children Actions (by definition, 0+) may not be the same Actions as the Restriction's parent Action.  Use [edit] and illustrate with actual data and I suspect you'll see the issue

Comment: Why do you have Restriction and Action as both parent and child of each other?  That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments, @DavidCheng and everyone. I continue working on this task using the Stack Exchange input and others. When the problem is resolved, I'll respond with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you have an outer query on Restrictions__c that will return a row for all Restrictions that have a parent Action.HR__c = '[###]'

You also have an inner query, meaning that for each Restrictions row returned, you also query a list of children Actions. This list of children Actions will only contain one action with the most recent createdDate and also whose HR__r.Name = '[###]'

To answer your second question first, The column: Actions__r actually represents a List of child Actions with the fields you select in the SELECT clause.
If there is no data, it means that for that Restrictions, wither no children Actions__r Exist, or no children Actions__r exist that meet your criteria of HR__r.Name

An example of this is querying Accounts with its Child Contacts:

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Contacts WHERE FirstName = 'Joe') FROM Account
```

- This query will return rows of **ALL** the Accounts in your org
- for each Account row, you will have a List (or rather a column) called Contacts
- inside the Contacts column, you will have a list of Contacts that have a first name of Joe. If there is no Contact with a FirstName of Joe for that given account, then the Contacts column will be blank. If an Account has child Contact(s) with a FirstName of Joe, the Id and Names of these contacts will be in the List.

In regards to your relationships between Restrictions__c and Actions__c, I understand you have a lookup field,

1. Restrictions__c.Action_ID__c
2. Actions__c.Actions_Restrictions__c

Are you able to use the **Parent** Action for Restrictions instead?

If that is the case, you can break down your question in the following way to design the query

*I need to return field Restriction_Description__c on Restrictions__c*

```
SELECT Restriction_Description__c FROM Restrictions__c
```

*where the [parent actions] HR ID field is '[###]'*.

```
WHERE Action_ID__r.hr__c = '[###]'
```

*where the CreatedDate (or could use the ID auto number field) field on [its parent] Actions__c is the most recent one,*

```
ORDER BY Action_ID__r.CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1
```

Does that help solve your problem?

Comment: Thank you for the time you took answering my question, Z33dawg and @cropredy.  
There are multiple rows returned for Restriction_Description__c where Action_ID__r.hr__c = '[###]' that can have different Created Dates and Action_ID__r.Names. I need to get the Restriction_Description__c field only for the latest Created Date or Action_ID__r.Name. BTW I tried creating a formula field for MAX(CreatedDate) and MAX(Action_ID__r.Names) but found I need a rollup summary field for getting MAX value for this purpose, and I need to use a query for the work if at all possible.